Dual boot Archcraft with Windows 10
So, i have windows 10 as main os and want to dual boot with Archcraft distro. Created bootable usb with Rufus and allocate 40GB of my ssd which is windows installed. The problem is Archcraft doesnt see my ssd. When i type "lsblk" in terminal it only shows usb partitions. Also tried to install with Calamares, neither it see ssd partitions. Note: my ssd is on RAID mode, if i need change it to AHCI, how can i do that without damage Windows 10?

From what you describe you need to have AHCI indeed. You  need to install AHCI support (google it) in Windows so it boots the same way after changing the setting.Changing from "RAID" to AHCI won't damage anything but Windows won't boot while in AHCI is it has no support for AHCI installed, that's all.

And, unless you really need to use the full hardware potential, use a VM instead of dual-booting. Anyone asking this kind of question will likely make mistakes.
